# Help me with my BitLockered drive (forgot 3 digits from the password, lost the recovery key)

Tags: bitlocker

I secured D drive partition of my laptop
But I lost the recovery key
I still have the password but lost 3 digits from it

Is there a way that I can recover the data?
Also will the drive "resist" in any way if I try the 999 combinations one by one?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much you can do other then trying to remember *very hard* what these 3 digits are. There is no known way to circumvent BitLocker in general. If you type in a wrong password several times, the system will report the "Too many PIN entry attempts" error message and then your only chance is the recovery key.

While I understand that you might find this regrettable, one should also not forget that this sort of security is the whole point of BitLocker.